# How to get the order book list with Binance API?

Tags: binance, binance-api-client

I would like to get the same information (opened orders) as displayed in order book on Binance site here:

[image]

I tried:

`/api/v3/allOrders` -- this apparently shows all MY orders

`api/v3/openOrders` -- this apparently shows opened MY orders

and

`/api/v3/trades` -- this apparently shows closed orders

How to see OPENED EVERYBODY'S orders?

Comment: How you are getting the Total? And are you showing asks or bids?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're looking for the Order Book endpoint.

Docs: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#order-book

Example: https://api.binance.com/api/v3/depth?limit=10&symbol=BTCUSDT

Comment: How can we get the whole order book without limiting it to a number?

Comment: @OmidEbrahimi Based on the linked docs page, the maximal limit is 5000, and there's no offset. There currently doesn't seem to be a way to retrieve records past the 5000.